# What is this Swift variable and how can I point to it with another variable?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

I have two variables containing arrays of Core Image filters, but they're objects I don't fully understand (is it some kind of closure maybe?):

```
var filterSet: [CIFilter] = { return [CIFilter1(), CIFilter2(), CIFilter3()] }()

var filterSetAlt: [CIFilter] = { return [CIFilter4(), CIFilter5(), CIFilter6()] }()
```

Later in the program I run through one or the other of these arrays with a `for` loop:

```
for eachFilter in self.filterSet {
    // apply eachFilter to image
```

I'd like to be able to set another variable `filterSetPicked` to either `filterSet` or `filterSetAlt` so that I only need one `for` loop (right now I use an `if-else` to pick which loop to run so I have a bunch of duplicated code).

When I try `var filterSetPicked = filterSet` Xcode cries that `ViewController.Type` does not have a member named `filterSet` — I assume that's because of the `filterSet` syntax `= { return [...] }()`, which looks sort of like some example closures I've seen, but not exactly.

Edit: Here is a simplified version of what I was trying to do:

```
class CIColorChannel1: CIFilter {
    var inputImage: CIImage!
    override var outputImage: CIImage! {
        get {
            return CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
                kCIInputImageKey : inputImage,
                "inputRVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                "inputGVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                "inputBVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1),
                "inputBiasVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                ]).outputImage
        }
    }
}

class CIColorChannel2: CIFilter {
    …
}    

class CIColorChannel3: CIFilter {
    …
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    var filterSet = [CIColorChannel1(), CIColorChannel2()]
    var filterSetAlt = [CIColorChannel2(), CIColorChannel3()]
    var filterSetPicked = filterSet

    func shutterButton() {
        for eachFilter in self.filterSetPicked {
            // take photo, apply filters 
            // (this part already works if I just use filterSet or filterSetAlt directly)
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws an error when trying to set `var filterSetPicked = filterSet`.

Comment: Post the whole Swift file, it's unclear where the problem is. We can just guess.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to expand it but I don't really want to share the whole Swift file, it's long and on another computer and only a bit of it seems at all relevant.

Comment: Then copy & paste it to new Playground, remove not needed lines, reproduce it and share complete Playground file with reproduced issue. If you think that only a bit of it seems relevant and you can't find the issue, it can be in a bit which seems irrelevant to you. Otherwise there's no way to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why what I was trying to do doesn't work, but I found a work around:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CIColorChannel1: CIFilter {
    var inputImage: CIImage!
    override var outputImage: CIImage! {
        get {
            return CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
                kCIInputImageKey : inputImage,
                "inputRVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                "inputGVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                "inputBVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1),
                "inputBiasVector" : CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
                ]).outputImage
        }
    }
}

class CIColorChannel2: CIFilter {
    ...
}

class CIColorChannel3: CIFilter {
    ...
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    var filterSet = [CIColorChannel1(), CIColorChannel2()]
    var filterSetAlt = [CIColorChannel2(), CIColorChannel3()]
    var filterSetPicked = []
    var filterSetting = true

    func shutterButton() {
        if self.filterSetting {
            self.filterSetPicked = self.filterSet
        } else {
            self.filterSetPicked = self.filterSetAlt
        }
        for eachFilter in self.filterSetPicked {
            // take photo, apply filters 
            // (this part already works if I just use filterSet or filterSetAlt directly)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no need to wrap your arrays with expressions like in your example. You can simplify your declarations like this:

```
var filterSet: [CIFilter] = [CIFilter1(), CIFilter2(), CIFilter3()]
```

You may even be able to declare it without the type and let the compiler infer:

```
var filterSet = [CIFilter1(), CIFilter2(), CIFilter3()]
```

Then there's no problem to assign `filterSet` to another variable (I just tested in a Playground):

```
var filterSetPicked = filterSet
```

And for your loop you probably just need to get rid of `self`:

```
for eachFilter in filterSet {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You were right I could remove the expressions wrapping my arrays, but I still can't assign `filterSet` to another variable I guess because it's inside of a class? (It builds when I set a `var exampleArray = ["one","two"]` and `var exampleArrayCopy = exampleArray`, but not when I move those into the class.

Comment: Well, it's hard to know without more context and details about how your code is organized.